# Question from years ago

Tags: support

I have the exact same question as this :[Sum of projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60967/sum-of-projections)

This was asked in 2011- I have asked my own question about it in the comments (you can see the comments) but sadly the original asker is happy and understands the solution unlike me- How do I "reawaken" the question so that somebody who posted in the thread replies- no new person will reply because it won't appear as a new question- it's been resolved- and many users who discussed it then at the time have not been seen on stackeexchange for months or years.

In general what do I do for future questions when a situation like this arises?

Comment: See [What to do when one wants to “revive” a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9242/what-to-do-when-one-wants-to-revive-a-question),
[Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer) and other posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, one is advised to set a bounty with the reason "Improve details: The current answers do not contain enough detail."

In the specific case, Daniel Fischer explained the answer in a comment, and also pointed out another question, [Problem with sum of projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507796), which contains a nice proof of the result in the question itself (the answer deals with a  more general problem). I then posted a CW-answer based on that question.

It seems that the answering method of "post a hint as an answer, follow it up by half a dozen clarifications in comments" has some visible drawbacks 5 years later.

Comment: Well, we should do something about incomplete answers.